# iOS 14 Messages swipe left to right to mark read

Tags: ios, messages, ui

I have noticed that swiping a message left to right in iOS Messages is suddenly pinning it instead of marking it read and it appears that the is no longer a quick way to mark a message read without opening it.

I am wondering if there is a way to change the behaviour back to how it was (mark message read by swiping left to right)?

Didn’t find any tips on that by googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change that behaviour back, as can be done with emails.

You can still bulk mark messages as read by clicking on `Edit > Select messages > Click on the messages > Read`.

Comment: Thank! It’s a shame that this behaviour change is not optional. So frustrating when such things change in a “take it and cope with it” approach...